# Pass parameters from Airflow to Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, airflow, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

I have configured logstash to listen the logs at default airflow logs path. I want to create the index in elasticsearch as {dag_id}-{task_id}-{execution_date}-{try_number}. All these are parameters from Airflow.  These are the modified values in airflow.cfg.

```
[core]
remote_logging = True

[elasticsearch]
host = 127.0.0.1:9200                                                                            
log_id_template = {{dag_id}}-{{task_id}}-{{execution_date}}-{{try_number}}                       
end_of_log_mark = end_of_log
write_stdout = True                                                                              
json_format = True                                                                               
json_fields = asctime, filename, lineno, levelname, message
```

These task instance details need to passed from Airflow to logstash.
dag_id, 
task_id, 
execution_date, 
try_number

This is my logstash config file.

```
input {
     file{                                                                                                  
       path => "/home/kmeenaravich/airflow/logs/Helloworld/*/*/*.log"                                   
       start_position => beginning                                                                    
     } 
}                                                                                                
output {                                                                                                  
     elasticsearch { 
        hosts => ["127.0.0.1:9200"]                                                                      
        index => "logginapp-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"                                                        
     }                                                                                                
     stdout { codec => rubydebug }                                                          
}
```

I have 2 questions. How to pass the parameters from Airflow to Logstash?

I have configured logstash to listen to the logs path. Since remote_logging is True in airfow.cfg, logs are not written to base log folder. If that is false or if I connect to Amazon S3, logs are written to base_log_folder path too. But, for me to configure logstash, logs need to be written in local folder. I use airflow version 1.10.9 . What can I do to stream my logs to Elasticsearch index.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question (I assume you mean passing the logs directly to Elasticsearch), you cannot. The Airflow "Elasticsearch Logging" is not really a logging to Elasticsearch but more a configuration to enable the logging to get shipped to Elasticsearch. The naming of the attributes is (in my opinion) a little bit confusing as it suggests that you can write directly to Elasticsearch.
You can configure Airflow to **read** logs from Elasticsearch. See [Airflow Elasticsearch documentation for more information](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/1.10.9/howto/write-logs.html#writing-logs-to-elasticsearch):

> Airflow can be configured to **read** task logs from Elasticsearch and
> optionally write logs to stdout in standard or json format. These logs
> can later be collected and forwarded to the Elasticsearch cluster
> using tools like fluentd, logstash or others.

As you have enabled `write_stdout = True`, output is written to stdout. If you want the output to be written in files you have to set `write_stdout = False` or leave it empty. Your logstash configuration should then find the files, which answers your second question.

Cheers
Michael

Comment: what about `write_remote` ?